# Can't start accounts app using django-userena

Tags: django, django-apps, django-userena

Tried to install django-userena, and when launching

```
python manage.py startapp polls
```

I get the userena.compat.SiteProfileNotAvailable error.

So this is very odd. 
First of all, official Django docs claims to depricate AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE setting : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.7/. 
But /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/userena/utils.py raises this error if it can't find AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE setting. Does it mean I can't use userena unless I downgrade to versions 1.6 or lower?

Secondly, I haven't created any models yet, so which profile I should have been addressing when starting app?

Django version 1.7.7, userena - 1.4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by uninstalling userena, creating accounts app, editing accounts/models.py file and only then installing userena.
Worked out perfectly