# Installing django-userena: userena.compat.SiteProfileNotAvailable when trying to create accounts app

Tags: python, django, user-accounts

Running Django 1.9 I'm trying to follow the install instructions for [django-userena](http://docs.django-userena.org/en/latest/installation.html), to add it to an existing django project.

When I try to create the Accounts app:

`python manage.py startapp accounts`

I get this error:

`userena.compat.SiteProfileNotAvailable`

[Other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809501/configuring-django-userena) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29362003/cant-start-accounts-app-using-django-userena) indicate that I need to set `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE`, as directed in the [installation instructions](http://docs.django-userena.org/en/latest/installation.html).  However, these assume I already have an Accounts app created, within which I've created a Profile model.

So I seem like I'm stuck in a circular dependancy where I can't create the Accounts app without a Profile model, but I can't create the Profile  model without the Accounts app!

Also, from the instructions, it doesn't appear the `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` should be required yet at this step, in order to create the Accounts app.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to that userena and the other apps are not yet installed, since
`manage.py startapp accounts` is the first step in the installation instructions.